# Twilio 30005 (Error: 30005) Unknown destination handset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio

I'm doing a simple integration of Twilio to send an outbound text with our App download links when user fills in his/her phone number.

I have verified my phone number on the trial account and am using this one to receive the message on.

When I trigger it on my website I see it in the logs but with error message 30005 even though this is the exact same number as the one I validated as "verified number".

Am I missing something here?

Simple call:

```
def send_sms(number)
  provided_number = ENV['provided_twilio_number']
  @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new ENV['my_code'] ENV['my_key']

  message = @client.account.messages.create(
    :from => provided_number,
    :to => number,
    :body => "my message"
  )
end
```

The output of 'number' is an exact match of what is displayed in my verified caller ID's.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) about this. They will be able to trace why the message returned a 30005 error when you're not expecting it to.

Answer (score 0):

Even though my phone number is correct when I tried with a colleagues number it worked just fine. Very strange that twilio thinks this is a faulty number even though they can verify it just fine. 
So trying with another number, not changing anything in code and it works ..

Answer (score 0):

Twilio's documentation on their 30005 error states:

> Repeated Error 30005 results on undelivered messages sent from toll-free numbers could be caused by carrier filtering. The rules for carrier filtering can vary throughout the industry, making it difficult at times to pin-down exactly why a message is being filtered out.

[Twilio's 30005 documentation page](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008704674-Error-30005-Message-Delivery-Unknown-destination-handset-when-Sending-SMS)

If you have used this number to send large amounts of SMS in the past, you may be blocked by some carriers.